# Sieve and MIME extension

Tags: mime-types, mime, dovecot, sieve-language

I have a sieve filter which looks like:

```
require ["mime", "imap4flags"];

if header :mime :contenttype "Content-Type" "message/upload-notification"
{
   setflag "\\Seen";
}
```

when I try to complie it to a binary version for Dovecot I'm receiving an error:

```
97-upload-processed: line 1: error: require command: unknown Sieve capability `mime'.
97-upload-processed: line 3: error: unknown tagged argument ':mime' for the header test (reported only once at first occurrence).
97-upload-processed: error: validation failed.
sievec(root): Error: failed to compile sieve script '97-upload-processed.sieve'
```

Did I have missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MIME extension for pigeonhole sieve is quite new (the [Wiki says it was added with pigeonhole v0.4.14](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Pigeonhole/Sieve) released April 2016, while the [changelog says it was in v0.4.10](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dovecot/pigeonhole/0.4.15/NEWS) released December 2015).

I was only able to retrieve the installed version of the installed pigeonhole version by querying `/usr/include/dovecot/sieve/pigeonhole-config.h`, you might find it under some different path, though.

Comment: It looks like I'm on 0.4.8. Thanks for pointing how to get pigeonhole version